# How to forward all local SMTP requests on port 25 to a remote SMTP server on port 587

Tags: networking, server, iptables, port-forwarding, smtp

I'm trying to solve a problem with a bulky program that is, for some reason, only sending email over port 25, even when port 587 is specified.

In [this answer](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/396494-lsi-megaraid-configure-alerts?page=1#entry-4602888), someone suggests using the windows command `netsh`:

`netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=25 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=587 connectaddress=%uFEFF%uFEFF<ipaddress of the real email server>`

Basically, it just changes the Windows IP rules such that anytime a connection over port 25 is made to 127.0.0.1, it forwards it to port 587 of the remote e-mail server.

I have seen some examples using `iptables` that come close, but I can't figure out the perfect one for forwarding to a *remote* e-mail server. Most iptable examples are only for forwarding within the local machine. If possible, I'd ike to use iptables with a domain name as well. Postfix is a bit annoying because it is a huge program when in reality, on a lot of servers, this ip rule will work a lot better for me

TL;DR If someone could help, I'd like to setup an ip rule to forward as follows:

```
Input domain: 127.0.0.1
Input port: 25
Output domain: smtp.gmail.com 
Output port: 587
```

This would also be useful for me for some other projects too.

Edit: 
Here are the commands that I have tried:

```
 sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 169.47.148.173:587 # The 169 ip is for smtp.sendgrid.net
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
iptables -F
```

I know the rules are active because i can list them with iptables nat command. `iptables -t nat -nvL`

But I still get a failure when trying to send the email through this stupid program, when specifying host `127.0.0.1` and port 25. I also specified a UDP forwarding rule too, still fails.